# Water tank question

Tags: calculus

There is an empty tank that has a hole in it. Water can enter the tank at the rate of 1 gallon per second. Water leaves the tank through the hole at the rate of 1 gallon per second for each 100 gallons in the tank. How long, in seconds, will it take to fill the 50 gallons of water. 
i think the rate is 1-1/100= 99/100. i dont know how to go from here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The tags you give a question are important, as it helps people to quickly see if they are able to help you. I changed your tag to `calculus` since leaky water tank problems are a standard in calculus, and precalculus is unable to directly solve such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The water doesn't go out at a constant rate, as it depends on how much water is in the tank. This gives the differential equation $y' = 1-\frac{y}{100}$ which is $\frac{dy}{dt} +\frac{y}{100} = 1$. Multiplying by the integrating factor $e^\frac{t}{100}$ gives $\frac{dy}{dt}e^\frac{t}{100} +\frac{y}{100}e^\frac{t}{100} = e^\frac{t}{100}$. By the product rule this is $\frac{d}{dt}[ye^\frac{t}{100}]=e^\frac{t}{100}$. Integrating both sides with respect to t gives $ye^\frac{t}{100}=100e^\frac{t}{100} + C$ so $y=100 + Ce^{-\frac{t}{100}}$. Plugging in the initial condition of $y(0)=0$ we get that $C=-100$, so $y(t)=100-100e^{-\frac{t}{100}}$.

We want to find when $y(t)=50$, so $50=100-100e^{-\frac{t}{100}}$ which is $\frac12=e^{-\frac{t}{100}}$, so $t=100\ln(2)$.